# Precision in calculation

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I am writing some code to demonstrate the effect of the number of significant figures a coefficient has on the solution of a nonlinear equation. I define the coefficient as follows:

```
sx = N[1/Sqrt[3], 5]
```

However, when I perform the calculations I notice that changing the precision (the number 5 in the above example) does not effect the results. Why can this be the case or am I using the wrong Mathematica function? You can also try the following for a minimal working example showing that indeed the roots do not change.

```
nx = 1.5
ny = 1.6
nz = 1.7
sx = N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]
sy = N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]
sz = N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]

NSolve[
 1/n^2 == sx^2 / (n^2 - nx^2) + sy^2 / (n^2 - ny^2) + 
   sz^2 / (n^2 - nz^2), n]
```

Comment: `nx`, `ny`, and `nz` are undefined

Comment: @JasonB I have defined them sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I think that the function `f` in Mr. Wizard's answer linked above may be what you want.  But let me ask you, when you say you want `N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]` which is `0.6`, do you want that precision maintained throughout calculations?  That is, if I enter `1/.6` it returns `1.66667` with a repeating decimal representation.  But if I force the precision to be 1 on this calculation like `1/N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]`, then it would be rounded to `2`

Comment: @JasonB I want that number to be regarded as `0.6` throughout the calculation.

Comment: Then you need to round it, as I do below,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the function `f` in Mr. Wizard's answer linked above may be what you want.

But let me ask you, when you say you want `N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]` which is `0.6`, do you want that precision maintained throughout calculations?

That is, if I enter `1/.6` it returns `1.66667` with a repeating decimal representation.  But if I force the precision to be 1 on this calculation like

```
1/N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]
(* 2. *)
```

then it would be rounded to `2`.  Here is the tricky part, when you multiply numbers with different precision, then the set precision is thrown out,

```
1.0/N[1/Sqrt[3], 1]
(* 1.73205 *)
```

So you may think the answer would be to wrap `nx`, `ny`, and `nz` in the same precision, but that seems to have no effect on the outcome of `NSolve`.  Giving `NSolve` the option `WorkingPrecision->1` has no effect either.

The only method that seems to influence the results from `NSolve` is strictly rounding the number.

Using a modified version of Mr. Wizard's function (the original doesn't have an effect here),

```
nRound[x_, n_] := 
  Round[x, 10.^(1 - n + ⌊Log10@Abs@x⌋)];
```

Then we get

```
nx = 1.5;
ny = 1.6;
nz = 1.7;
sx = nRound[1/Sqrt[3], 1];
sy = nRound[1/Sqrt[3], 1];
sz = nRound[1/Sqrt[3], 1];

NSolve[1/n^2 == 
  sx^2/(n^2 - nx^2) + sy^2/(n^2 - ny^2) + sz^2/(n^2 - nz^2), n, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 2]
(* {{n -> 0. + 5.66204 I}, {n -> 
   0. - 5.66204 I}, {n -> -1.65497}, {n -> 1.65497}, {n -> 
   1.5394}, {n -> -1.5394}} *)
```

Changing the 1 to a 3 gives

```
{{n -> -45.9999}, {n -> 45.9999}, {n -> 
   1.65466}, {n -> -1.65466}, {n -> -1.53909}, {n -> 1.53909}}
```

Comment: Okay this works, but is there a one line alternative that is already built-in? I think that the function N is only for output formatting purposes. This seems a bit overkill for such a simple task.